# group by clause in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have been through the below code but dont understand how group clause makes the grouping

Please help in this . I am new to c# .

```
public static List<Student> GetStudents()
        {
            // Use a collection initializer to create the data source. Note that each element 
            //  in the list contains an inner sequence of scores.
            List<Student> students = new List<Student>
        {
           new Student {First="Svetlana", Last="Omelchenko", ID=111, Scores= new List<int> {97, 72, 81, 60}},
           new Student {First="Claire", Last="O'Donnell", ID=112, Scores= new List<int> {75, 84, 91, 39}},
           new Student {First="Sven", Last="Mortensen", ID=113, Scores= new List<int> {99, 89, 91, 95}},
           new Student {First="Cesar", Last="Garcia", ID=114, Scores= new List<int> {72, 81, 65, 84}},
           new Student {First="Debra", Last="Garcia", ID=115, Scores= new List<int> {97, 89, 85, 82}} 
        };

            return students;

        }
List<Student> students = GetStudents();

            // Write the query. 
            var studentQuery =
                from student in students
                let avg = (int)student.Scores.Average()
                group student by (avg == 0 ? 0 : avg / 10);
```

I dont understand how StudentQuery has been generated .
Thanks in advance .

Comment: This **is not** the matter **a new Learner** has to care about, I'm pretty sure that many `LINQ users` just know **How to use it** even without noticing **How it's implemented**, learning stuff like this will **slow you down**. It's similar that **When you learn WPF, you always wonder How it renders 3D Visual**. Of course it should be cared about BUT it's an **advanced** topic, not for a Learner at all.

Comment: Thanks king king . A very good advice i got after a long time . i am from c++ background , i have started c# few days back . can you please tell me which way i should proceed . and i want to go for a microsoft certification too . please help .thanks in adv .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping refers to the operation of putting data into groups so that the elements in each group share a common attribute.The `GroupBy` divides students into groups - those with average 0-9, 10-19, 20-29, 30-39, etc. You should look at 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb546139.aspx

p.s. the

```
 group student by (avg == 0 ? 0 : avg / 10);
```

seems to be excessive to me. You can change it to simplier

```
 group student by (avg / 10);
```

pps: I prefer the other style of LINQ, but it's totally a personal choice. The other style would be

```
var studentQuery = students.GroupBy(x => x.Scores.Average() / 10);
```

Comment: Its better to go for lambda . :)